# Random reboot issue with ARM processors

Tags: amazon-ec2, arm

I am using 64 bit ARM processor based EC2 instance from AWS and overall performance is satisfactory. But the server reboots randomly without any apparent reason. Is this expected with ARM processors? I am asking because I never experienced this on my other EC2 instances (with x86 processors).

Comment: not expected no

Comment: Do your phone, tablet, ECUs in your car, and a million other ARM-based devices reboot randomly? This probably has nothing to do with ARM, but possibly some AWS-specific software (configuration) problem.

Comment: No, definitely not a normal experience; which arm instance types and region was this occurring?  A better forum to ask for help would be the AWS Forums, in the EC2 topic.  You can also try emailing: ec2-arm-dev-feedback@amazon.com on this issue as well.